# Retriev the value of array of objects in servlet

Tags: java, servlets

How to retrieve the array of objects in servlet.

I have an array object of the form in javascript

```
var studentArr ={
                 {id: 1 , name : pUJA , mob : 455},
                 {id:2, name : Pinky , mob : 598}
                };
```

How to retrieve the array in servlet when passed from javascript

Comment: is it an array or json array?

Comment: array object which i form in javascript

Comment: Use inputtype hidden and send it with the next request.

Comment: plz guide me how to retrieve the array in servlet

Answer (score 0):

for your example:

```
var studentArr = {data: [{id: 1 , name : pUJA , mob : 455},{id:2, name : Pinky , mob : 598}]}; // place [ and ] and make it in json format then
```

you will have to do something of this effect:

```
JSONObject myjson = new JSONObject(studentArr );
JSONArray the_json_array = myjson.getJSONArray("data");
```

this returns the array object.

Then iterating will be as follows:

```
    int size = the_json_array.length();
    ArrayList<JSONObject> arrays = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        JSONObject another_json_object = the_json_array.getJSONObject(i);
            //Blah blah blah...
            arrays.add(another_json_object);
    }

//Finally
JSONObject[] jsons = new JSONObject[arrays.size()];
arrays.toArray(jsons);

//The end...
```

You will have to determine if the data is an array (simply checking that `charAt(0)` starts with `[` character).

Hope this helps.

Anthoer [Java json tute](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html) is here ....

Comment: i want to do it using servlet not json .

Comment: Not a valid JSON ....though ... {
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "pUJA",
            "mob": 455
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Pinky",
            "mob": 598
        }
    ]
}`

Comment: i need to retrieve the array from javascript i am passing to servlet . How to retrieve it in servlet?